# OpenLayers with MVC and SQL Server

Tags: openlayers-2, sql-server

I have imported some shape files into SQL Server 2008. Now i want to use OpenLayers with my MVC 4 application to render those shape files from SQL Server Database.

Any help in this regard?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to edit your Question to include details of what you have already tried with OpenLayers, and where you are stuck, please?

Comment: I am new to open layers. I have imported my shape files into SQL server by using SHP-to-SQL tool. Now i have the shape file in SQL server. I want to render those shape files in my view and query some data. I just dont know how to move forword from here.

Comment: There is a possible duplicate of [A good tutorial for Openlayers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78685/a-good-tutorial-for-openlayers) available to help you get started.  Once you have reviewed/tried some/all of the suggestions there I think you will be in a better position to **edit your Question** into something that is more focussed.

Comment: I'm voting to keep it open, since the linked answer doesn't show how to actually create a WMS service, or some other service/protocol which OpenLayers can use.

Answer (score 3):

The database, only stores the data, and you need some way of getting that data in a format which OpenLayers will understand.

The easiest way of doing this would be to have a WMS server which can connect to your database, and serve out the data as a WMS service which you can then consume in OpenLayers.

I'll suggest that you look into using [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/). Using [an extension](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-install), you can connect to spatial data in MS SQL from Geoserver. Please see [this documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlserver.html) page for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this but with Postgres. You could create an action to get the json from the controller to the html. Openlayers can create a layer using json data or geojson, using something like this:

> ```
>    var xhttp;
>    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
>    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
>    {
>        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
>        {
>            return xhttp;
>        }
>    };
>    xhttp.open("GET", 'g_estados/GetEstadosJson', false);
>    xhttp.send();
>
>    var data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
>
>    var format = new ol.format.WKT();
>    var features = new Array();
>
>    for (i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++)
>    {
>        var fea = format.readFeature(data[i].wkt, {
>            dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
>            featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
>        });
>
>        fea.setId(data[i]['id']);
>        features.push(fea);
>    }
>
>    var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
>        id: 'test',
>        name: 'test',
>        source: new ol.source.Vector({
>            useSpatialIndex: true,
>            format: 'wkt',
>            features: features
>        }),
>        visible: true
>    });
>    map.addLayer(layer);
> ```

and an Action like this:

> ```
>    public JsonResult GetEstadosJson()
>    {
>        IEnumerable<g_estado> data = db.g_estado.ToList();
>
>        return new JsonResult()
>        {
>            Data = data,
>            MaxJsonLength = 86753090,
>            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
>        };
>    }
> ```

MaxJsonLenght limits the size of data returned in the action, so make sure there is not a lot of data to return, it could produce 2 kind of errors, limit exceeded or out of memory if this get too long.