# Building web application to get PostGIS query from user and view result map using GeoServer via OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, geoserver

I'm a newbie in web-map application area.

I just found the small application in this [tutorial](http://www.gistutor.com/postgresqlpostgis/10-intermediate-postgresqlpostgis-tutorials/75-understanding-postgis-spatial-queries.html) interesting

I am a bit confused, because when I publish a map using GeoServer and OpenLayers, I have to create a layer in GeoServer first and **this layer is fixed with a table from PostGIS** and then use OpenLayers to call GeoServer to render the map.

- How can the tutor of that tutorial change the data source of the layer depending on the query input by the users?
- It means there are ways to change the data source of one layer on the fly right?

Please advice me how or can anyone tell me where can I download the code of the app in that tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to start at the very beginning to get your head around the basics of GeoServer first.

There is a good Question and Answer set available [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7987/tutorials-for-geoserver) on how to use GeoServer

Some good information on OpenLayers Tutorials can be found [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78685/a-good-tutorial-for-openlayers)

and some interesting Tutorials on PostGis [here](http://www.gistutor.com/postgresqlpostgis/4-beginner-postgresqlpostgis-tutorials.html)

There is a lot of sample code that will help you in those reference ..